# Jumping ring demonstration

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, ferromagnetism

In demonstration of jumping ring if we assume dc source connected to solenoid, according to most of books, when we place a metallic ring over the solenoid and as soon as we turned on current, due to change in flux an opposite current induces in ring and causes a very high repulsion and ring flies off, but my problem is that generally almost everywhere they consider ring of aluminium or copper and derive a rigorous mathematical model of it but what happen if instead of copper or aluminium we take a ring of ferromagnetic material (steel)? In that case what will be behaviour of ring i.e attraction (because ferromagnetic material attracted towards solenoid due to magnetic field gradient) or repulsion due to lenz law? And can we derive rigorous mathematical model in that case

Comment: What is a jumping ring?

Comment: The jumping ring demonstration is often/usually done with an as power supply.